# Self referencing email form in Sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I am a content editor new to Sharepoint and have to build a registration form for a training department. As there is no need to access a db, I have been told InfoPath is not required, is this correct?

If not using Infopath, can I just build a form using html in either a content web part or page content area? I have intermediate html skills but am unsure whether Sharepoint will support any scripting, and, if so ,which language - I assume asp.net of which I know nothing, my skills being more php based.

There is nothing tricky about most of the form itself. The applicant fills in their details including their line manager's email address. The main place I get unstuck is the form is then submitted to the line manager, who's address is an input to the form, for approval. As this will change everytime, I assume a script is required, but there is where my knowledge runs out and I cannot find a similar question after several days searching the web.

I assume I will also need a script to validate the email address (not compare it to a db, just for making sure it is a valid email format).

Is anyone able to point me in the direction of some of these answers? I am not asking for someone to code it for me, but It would be helpful if you know of a tutorial site where I could learn to do this myself.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found what I am after at [this site](http://www.tutorialized.com/view/tutorial/Self-Referencing-Forms/2087)